# Which built-in abstract base classes support slicing?

Tags: python, slice, abstract-base-class

The documentation of Python lists all the methods that implementations of abstract base classes should have very clearly at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html. 
Slicing is however only sometimes implemented as part of `__getitem__`.

I would imagine all classes inheriting from `Sequence` would implement it, is that the case? Are there any other ways of knowing that an object supports slicing?

Edit: I also found https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common in the documentation. It lists the methods as 'supported by most sequence types'.
I'll take that as 'Sequence types should implement slicing' and annotate using that.

Comment: The "pythonic" way is to try doing it and seeing if an exception is raised.

Comment: There was once a `__getslice__` method, but that was superceded *long* ago by passing a `slice` object to `__getitem__`. There isn't really a class of types that specifically implement slicing, just as there is no separate class of types that can be indexed with `int` value vs those that can be indexed with `str` values.

Comment: It seems *implicit* that a `Sequence` is a type whose order is determined by an ordering of its indices, while a `Mapping` is one whose order (if defined at all) is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `typeshed/typing.pyi`, Sequence is typed as follows:

```
class Sequence(_Collection[_T_co], Reversible[_T_co], Generic[_T_co]):
    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> _T_co: ...
    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, s: slice) -> Sequence[_T_co]: ...
    ...
```

https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/typing.pyi#L274

Any Sequence type should therefore support slicing. Slices are not indicated for other types in the typing module. A Mapping for example explicitly lists the key type of the mapping.

Comment: Be careful making assumptions based on type hints. For example, `Mapping` is completely generic in both its key types and value types, but `dict` doesn't allow non-hashable keys. This says that a `Sequence` *can* support a `slice` object as an argument, but beyond the return type being another sequence with the same element types, nothing about how the `slice` should be used. (The type hint allows, for example, that every slicing operation return an empty tuple, no matter the concrete sequence type.)

Comment: Interesting, dict is also completely generic in its key type. It seems Hashable is a special case that they haven't figured out yet.

Comment: Given that the official (typing) implementation indicates that slicing is supported on Sequences I will go with that. It's possible in Python that you indicate something as a subclass without implementing the abstract methods (correctly), but we can say that for any subclass.  
I'd rather consider those cases as bugs, than refrain from using the type hints.

Comment: I agree that a class that implements slicing *should* be a subclass of `Sequence`; I just disagree that being a subclass of `Sequence` *guarantees* that slicing is supported.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR There's no such subclass, because Python only defines the *syntax* of slicing, not any semantics.

---

In order to be a subclass of `Sequence` or `Mapping`, a class must implement `__getitem__`. However, neither ABC mandates any particular implementation of `__getitem__`; it's entirely up to the implementing class how to interpret the index argument.

Slicing isn't really a special operation; it's just special syntax for specifying an argument of type `slice`. The following are equivalent:

```
foo[1:3,2::9]
foo[slice(1,3), slice(2,None,9)]
```

As far as the *signature* of `__getitem__` is concerned, there is no difference between passing it a single `int`, a `str`, a `slice` object, or a tuple containing any combination of types.